# Bubble chart :Cannot read property 'parts/Globals.js' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I am using 'react-highcharts' for rendering charts in my project. Simple charts such as bar chart ,pie chart are working fine .But when I am trying to render bubble charts, I am getting typeerror.

Here is the implementation:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactHighcharts from 'react-highcharts';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts/highcharts';
import HC_MORE from 'highcharts/highcharts-more';


const BubbleChart = (props) => {
  if (typeof Highcharts === 'object') {

    HC_MORE(Highcharts);
  }
  const config = {
    chart: {
      type: 'packedbubble',
      height: '100%',
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Carbon emissions around the world (2014)',
    },
    tooltip: {
      useHTML: true,
      pointFormat: '<b>{point.name}:</b> {point.value}m CO<sub>2</sub>',
    },
    plotOptions: {
      packedbubble: {
        minSize: '30%',
        maxSize: '120%',
        zMin: 0,
        zMax: 1000,
        layoutAlgorithm: {
          splitSeries: false,
          gravitationalConstant: 0.02,
        },
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          format: '{point.name}',
          filter: {
            property: 'y',
            operator: '>',
            value: 250,
          },
          style: {
            color: 'black',
            textOutline: 'none',
            fontWeight: 'normal',
          },
        },
      },
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Europe',
      data: [{
        name: 'Germany',
        value: 767.1,
      }, {
        name: 'Croatia',
        value: 20.7,
      },
      {
        name: 'Belgium',
        value: 97.2,
      },
      {
        name: 'Czech Republic',
        value: 111.7,
      },
      {
        name: 'Netherlands',
        value: 158.1,
      },
      {
        name: 'Spain',
        value: 241.6,
      },
      {
        name: 'Ukraine',
        value: 249.1,
      },
      {
        name: 'Poland',
        value: 298.1,
      },
      {
        name: 'France',
        value: 323.7,
      },
      {
        name: 'Romania',
        value: 78.3,
      },
      {
        name: 'United Kingdom',
        value: 415.4,
      }, {
        name: 'Turkey',
        value: 353.2,
      }, {
        name: 'Italy',
        value: 337.6,
      },
      {
        name: 'Greece',
        value: 71.1,
      },
      {
        name: 'Austria',
        value: 69.8,
      },
      {
        name: 'Belarus',
        value: 67.7,
      },
      {
        name: 'Serbia',
        value: 59.3,
      },
      {
        name: 'Finland',
        value: 54.8,
      },
      {
        name: 'Bulgaria',
        value: 51.2,
      },
      {
        name: 'Portugal',
        value: 48.3,
      },
      {
        name: 'Norway',
        value: 44.4,
      },
      {
        name: 'Sweden',
        value: 44.3,
      },
      {
        name: 'Hungary',
        value: 43.7,
      },
      {
        name: 'Switzerland',
        value: 40.2,
      },
      {
        name: 'Denmark',
        value: 40,
      },
      {
        name: 'Slovakia',
        value: 34.7,
      },
      {
        name: 'Ireland',
        value: 34.6,
      },
      {
        name: 'Croatia',
        value: 20.7,
      },
      {
        name: 'Estonia',
        value: 19.4,
      },
      {
        name: 'Slovenia',
        value: 16.7,
      },
      {
        name: 'Lithuania',
        value: 12.3,
      },
      {
        name: 'Luxembourg',
        value: 10.4,
      },
      {
        name: 'Macedonia',
        value: 9.5,
      },
      {
        name: 'Moldova',
        value: 7.8,
      },
      {
        name: 'Latvia',
        value: 7.5,
      },
      {
        name: 'Cyprus',
        value: 7.2,
      }],
    }, {
      name: 'Africa',
      data: [{
        name: 'Senegal',
        value: 8.2,
      },
      {
        name: 'Cameroon',
        value: 9.2,
      },
      {
        name: 'Zimbabwe',
        value: 13.1,
      },
      {
        name: 'Ghana',
        value: 14.1,
      },
      {
        name: 'Kenya',
        value: 14.1,
      },
      {
        name: 'Sudan',
        value: 17.3,
      },
      {
        name: 'Tunisia',
        value: 24.3,
      },
      {
        name: 'Angola',
        value: 25,
      },
      {
        name: 'Libya',
        value: 50.6,
      },
      {
        name: 'Ivory Coast',
        value: 7.3,
      },
      {
        name: 'Morocco',
        value: 60.7,
      },
      {
        name: 'Ethiopia',
        value: 8.9,
      },
      {
        name: 'United Republic of Tanzania',
        value: 9.1,
      },
      {
        name: 'Nigeria',
        value: 93.9,
      },
      {
        name: 'South Africa',
        value: 392.7,
      }, {
        name: 'Egypt',
        value: 225.1,
      }, {
        name: 'Algeria',
        value: 141.5,
      }],
    }, {
      name: 'Oceania',
      data: [{
        name: 'Australia',
        value: 409.4,
      },
      {
        name: 'New Zealand',
        value: 34.1,
      },
      {
        name: 'Papua New Guinea',
        value: 7.1,
      }],
    }, {
      name: 'North America',
      data: [{
        name: 'Costa Rica',
        value: 7.6,
      },
      {
        name: 'Honduras',
        value: 8.4,
      },
      {
        name: 'Jamaica',
        value: 8.3,
      },
      {
        name: 'Panama',
        value: 10.2,
      },
      {
        name: 'Guatemala',
        value: 12,
      },
      {
        name: 'Dominican Republic',
        value: 23.4,
      },
      {
        name: 'Cuba',
        value: 30.2,
      },
      {
        name: 'USA',
        value: 5334.5,
      }, {
        name: 'Canada',
        value: 566,
      }, {
        name: 'Mexico',
        value: 456.3,
      }],
    }, {
      name: 'South America',
      data: [{
        name: 'El Salvador',
        value: 7.2,
      },
      {
        name: 'Uruguay',
        value: 8.1,
      },
      {
        name: 'Bolivia',
        value: 17.8,
      },
      {
        name: 'Trinidad and Tobago',
        value: 34,
      },
      {
        name: 'Ecuador',
        value: 43,
      },
      {
        name: 'Chile',
        value: 78.6,
      },
      {
        name: 'Peru',
        value: 52,
      },
      {
        name: 'Colombia',
        value: 74.1,
      },
      {
        name: 'Brazil',
        value: 501.1,
      }, {
        name: 'Argentina',
        value: 199,
      },
      {
        name: 'Venezuela',
        value: 195.2,
      }],
    }, {
      name: 'Asia',
      data: [{
        name: 'Nepal',
        value: 6.5,
      },
      {
        name: 'Georgia',
        value: 6.5,
      },
      {
        name: 'Brunei Darussalam',
        value: 7.4,
      },
      {
        name: 'Kyrgyzstan',
        value: 7.4,
      },
      {
        name: 'Afghanistan',
        value: 7.9,
      },
      {
        name: 'Myanmar',
        value: 9.1,
      },
      {
        name: 'Mongolia',
        value: 14.7,
      },
      {
        name: 'Sri Lanka',
        value: 16.6,
      },
      {
        name: 'Bahrain',
        value: 20.5,
      },
      {
        name: 'Yemen',
        value: 22.6,
      },
      {
        name: 'Jordan',
        value: 22.3,
      },
      {
        name: 'Lebanon',
        value: 21.1,
      },
      {
        name: 'Azerbaijan',
        value: 31.7,
      },
      {
        name: 'Singapore',
        value: 47.8,
      },
      {
        name: 'Hong Kong',
        value: 49.9,
      },
      {
        name: 'Syria',
        value: 52.7,
      },
      {
        name: 'DPR Korea',
        value: 59.9,
      },
      {
        name: 'Israel',
        value: 64.8,
      },
      {
        name: 'Turkmenistan',
        value: 70.6,
      },
      {
        name: 'Oman',
        value: 74.3,
      },
      {
        name: 'Qatar',
        value: 88.8,
      },
      {
        name: 'Philippines',
        value: 96.9,
      },
      {
        name: 'Kuwait',
        value: 98.6,
      },
      {
        name: 'Uzbekistan',
        value: 122.6,
      },
      {
        name: 'Iraq',
        value: 139.9,
      },
      {
        name: 'Pakistan',
        value: 158.1,
      },
      {
        name: 'Vietnam',
        value: 190.2,
      },
      {
        name: 'United Arab Emirates',
        value: 201.1,
      },
      {
        name: 'Malaysia',
        value: 227.5,
      },
      {
        name: 'Kazakhstan',
        value: 236.2,
      },
      {
        name: 'Thailand',
        value: 272,
      },
      {
        name: 'Taiwan',
        value: 276.7,
      },
      {
        name: 'Indonesia',
        value: 453,
      },
      {
        name: 'Saudi Arabia',
        value: 494.8,
      },
      {
        name: 'Japan',
        value: 1278.9,
      },
      {
        name: 'China',
        value: 10540.8,
      },
      {
        name: 'India',
        value: 2341.9,
      },
      {
        name: 'Russia',
        value: 1766.4,
      },
      {
        name: 'Iran',
        value: 618.2,
      },
      {
        name: 'Korea',
        value: 610.1,
      }],
    }],
  };
  return (
    <ReactHighcharts config={config} />
  );
};

BubbleChart.propTypes = {

};

export default BubbleChart;
```

When rendered, the above code gives error as

```
Cannot read property 'parts/Globals.js' of undefined
```

Any suggestion on how to debug this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

Highcharts released a new version a few days back. They have fixed an issue(10232) which is causing this error. 
If you encounter this error, you might want to check that your app is not server-rendered. In the case that it is server-rendered then the following should fix the issue:

Check that highchart is a type of 'object' because on the server it is of type 'function'. If it is an object then you want to execute the module you want. Kindly see below:

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts/highcharts';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';
import highchartsBellCurve from 'highcharts/modules/histogram-bellcurve';

if (typeof Highcharts === 'object') {
  highchartsBellCurve(Highcharts); // Execute the bell curve module
}
```

OR
Check my js-fiddle with your config: https://jsfiddle.net/prak_mtl/p6a3jemd/13/

Comment: typeOf Highcharts returns object ,implemented the above solution but that doesnt help

Comment: Have editted the question with the latest implementation.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I encourage to use the highcharts-react-official wrapper: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react which is fully supported by Highcharts support team.

npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-react-official

Next, as is suggested in the GitHub documentation I encourage to define chart options in the state.

Demo with using hooks: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-n7o2s

Demo with using the class component: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-jqv95